# Running a powershell script from ansible and register output

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, windows-installer

I am trying to run a Powershell script which reads ProductGUID from an MSI file, using ansible on a remote Windows PC. The powershell is working as a ps1 file, locally on the bench. But from ansible it throws an error saying the object reference was not set to an instance of an object.

Here is my ansible code

```
- name: Run PowerShell script to find out Product Code
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
           $windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
           $database = $windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase($msiFilePath, 0)
           $query = 'SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = ''ProductCode'''
           $view = $database.OpenView($query)
           $view.Execute()
           $record = $view.Fetch()

           if ($record) {
                $productGUID = $record.StringData(1)
                echo "Product GUID: $productGUID"
           } else {
                echo "Product GUID not found in the MSI file."
           }

           if ($view) {
                $view.Close()
           }
    parameters:
      msiFilePath: '<Path_to_MSI>'
  register: PS_output
  tags:
    - read_msi

- name: Show PS_output
  debug:
    var: PS_output
  tags:
    - read_msi
```

Output shows:

> changed: [mb018-windows] => {
> "changed": true,
> "debug": [],
> "error": [
> {
> "category_info": {
> "activity": "",
> "category": "OperationStopped",
> "category_id": 14,
> "reason": "NullReferenceException",
> "target_name": "",
> "target_type": ""
> },
> "error_details": null,
> "exception": {
> "help_link": null,
> "hresult": -2147467261,
> "inner_exception": null,
> "message": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
> "source": "System.Management.Automation",
> "type": "System.NullReferenceException"
> },
> "fully_qualified_error_id": "System.NullReferenceException",
> "output": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\nAt line:2 char:1\r\n+ $database = $windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase($msiFilePath, 0)\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], NullReferenceException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException\r\n \r\n",
> "pipeline_iteration_info": [],
> "script_stack_trace": "at , : line 2",
> "target_object": null
> },
> {
> "category_info": {
> "activity": "",
> "category": "InvalidOperation",
> "category_id": 7,
> "reason": "RuntimeException",
> "target_name": "",
> "target_type": ""
> },
> "error_details": null,
> "exception": {
> "help_link": null,
> "hresult": -2146233087,
> "inner_exception": null,
> "message": "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.",
> "source": "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly",
> "type": "System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException"
> },
> "fully_qualified_error_id": "InvokeMethodOnNull",
> "output": "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.\r\nAt line:4 char:1\r\n+ $view = $database.OpenView($query)\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull\r\n \r\n",
> "pipeline_iteration_info": [],
> "script_stack_trace": "at , : line 4",
> "target_object": null
> },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Variable `$msiFilePath` is not set in your inline PowerShell script, which makes it evaluate to `$null`.

  - Passing `$null` as the MSI file path to the [`.OpenDatabase()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installer-opendatabase) results in the (obscure) error message you saw.
- While you do pass an `msiFilePath` parameter on the Ansible side, for that value to become a *PowerShell variable* with that name, you **must declare your PowerShell script with parameter(s)**, *named for the keys in the key-value pairs in the `parameters:` YAML section*, using a `param(...)` block, as shown below:

```yaml
...

    script: |
           # DECLARE YOUR PARAMETER(S) HERE.
           # The name(s) must match the ones in the parameters: YAML section.
           param([string] $msiFilePath)

           $windowsInstaller = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
           $database = $windowsInstaller.OpenDatabase($msiFilePath, 0)
           $query = 'SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = ''ProductCode'''
           $view = $database.OpenView($query)
           $view.Execute()
           $record = $view.Fetch()

           if ($record) {
                $productGUID = $record.StringData(1)
                echo "Product GUID: $productGUID"
           } else {
                echo "Product GUID not found in the MSI file."
           }

           if ($view) {
                $view.Close()
           }
    parameters:
      msiFilePath: '<Path_to_MSI>'

...
```

Note:

- The above technique is shown in an [example in the docs for the `ansible.windows.win_powershell` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html#examples).
- For more information on declaring parameters for PowerShell scripts and functions, see the [relevant section of the `about_Functions` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters).
- The way that the key-value pairs in the `parameters:` YAML section are translated to PowerShell parameters is analogous to how hashtable-based [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) works inside PowerShell.